# How can I fix this not working redirection to a not working URL containing an ' character?

Tags: c#, .net, url, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 application (but my problem is not strictly related to SharePoint) and I have the following problem.

Into a webpart I have a **LinkButton** like this:

```
string url2 = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/ARXEIA WEBPART/Aggiungi allegato.aspx?IdItem=" + item.ID + "&AttachName=" +
                        nomeAllegato + "&Mode=Delete&IsDlg=1";
LinkButton linkDel = new LinkButton();
linkDel.Text = "Elimina";

string url2 = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/ARXEIA WEBPART/Aggiungi allegato.aspx?IdItem=" + item.ID + "&AttachName=" +
    nomeAllegato + "&Mode=Delete&IsDlg=1";

linkDel.OnClientClick = "if(confirm('Attenzione, verrà rimosso un allegato. Continuare?')){openEditRedAtt('" + url2 + "');return false;}else{return false;}";
```

The **OnClientClick** property contains this value:

```
"if(confirm('Attenzione, verrà rimosso un allegato. Continuare?')){openEditRedAtt('http://nabucodonosor:8080/Protocollo/pg/ARXEIA WEBPART/Aggiungi allegato.aspx?IdItem=580&AttachName=con un'apice.pdf&Mode=Delete&IsDlg=1');return false;}else{return false;}"
```

That should redirect to another web part. The problem is that in this specific case the URL contains an URL parameter containing a **'** character, this one:

```
AttachName=con un'apice.pdf
```

it is causing a malfunction. It is as the call is not performed so it is not correctly redirected to the target webpart.

This wrong value is contained into the **nomeAllegato** variable.

How can I handle this kind of situation? Have I to escape the character in some way? How can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected in web URL you need to escape certain characters, in your case you need to replace ' for %27 but i ll leave a webpage where you can find the rest of them if you like

https://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters/